# How to split in a string only when delimiter does not occur in code-formatted block?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm making an app that splits markdown content at each '---', and displays each as a slide.

However, there is an error of splitting when there is a `---` in a code block. In that case it should not be used as a split delimiter.

How can I split the input by '---', ignoring any such mark in code blocks?

Example:

````js
const str = `

slide1

--- // This is the delimiter to split the string into slides.

```code 
-
--
--- // I don't want to split here, as it is part of a code block
``` // 

--- // Another delimiter to split at.

slide2

---

```code 
var a = 0
``` //


`
````

The expected output should consist of 4 parts, not 5:

````js
[`

slide1

`,

`
```code 
-
--
--- // I don't want to split here, as it is part of a code block
``` // 

`,

`
slide2

---

```code 
var a = 0
``` //


`]
````

Comment: You cannot use unescaped backticks in a template literal like that. This represents invalid JavaScript syntax.

Comment: Also, in your expected output, why is `---` not splitting just below "slide2"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `match` instead of `split`, and swallow code blocks in one go, while eating other characters one by one as long as they are not the start of `---` at the beginning of a line:

````js
const str = `

slide1

--- // This is the delimiter to split the string into slides.

\`\`\`code 
-
--
--- // I don't want to split here, as it is part of a code block
\`\`\` // 

--- // Another delimiter to split at.

slide2

---

\`\`\`code 
var a = 0
\`\`\` //


`;

let res = str.match(/^(```.*?```|(?!^---).)+/gms);
console.log(res);
````

Comment: Thank you very much. Thanks to you I solved this problem in 10 hours!!!

Comment: May I ask you just one more thing? Your answer was such a great solution. However, when there are multiple code blocks, a problem occurs that does not work properly. If there are multiple code blocks, how can you solve it?

Comment: Thank you for quick response. I changed the example in the question, can you show me some sample code that solves that example? I don't know if I understood the hint you wrote well.

I'm new to Stack Overflow, so I didn't know that I had to mark a question that was answered. I'll mark it right away thanks for letting me know

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind sample code. Unfortunately, what I'm working on right now is making slides from what users write in Markdown. If there are multiple blocks of code, I'm not sure how to separate them and apply those regular expressions. Could it be possible to explain with the code in the question I updated?

Comment: OK, I see what you mean now. Updated the regular expression: add a `?` just after `.*` so it becomes non-greedy.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this;

````js
const str = `

slide1
---

\`\`\`code --- - --\`\`\` // I want to exclude strings between these code blocks

\`\`\`code2 --- - --\`\`\`
---
slide2


`

console.log("Original:" + str)
console.log("Replaced:" + str.replaceAll(/```(.*)```/gm,"$1"))
````

Comment: Oh my god! Thank you very much for replying. However, in the above method, all content in the code block disappears. How can I leave the content inside the code block?

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. But I guess I didn't explain the intent of the question well. I want to make a slide by splitting only '---' outside the code block, but I still can't solve the problem. What kind of regular expression can I use to split into '---' only in strings outside the ```codeblock ```?